# Search for opened tabs in chrome using Vimium

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, vimium

Does Vimium have a key mapping to search for a already opened tab?

A use case would be I have a "www.facebook.com" tab opened in my browser along with 20 other tabs. I want to use Vimium to search if there is already a "www.facebook.com" tab open and jump to that tab if it is present.

Answer (score 35):

Use the capital <kbd>T</kbd> to search through your open tabs.

Comment: How have I not used this sooner??? Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Press `?` to see Vimium's shortcuts. The shortcut you want is there and, now, you know how to fish.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
o       Open URL, bookmark, or history entry
O       Open URL, bookmark, history entry in a new tab
b       Open bookmark
B       Open bookmark in a new tab
```

Source: https://github.com/philc/vimium#keyboard-bindings